# Does Azure Maps send image overlays to the cloud?

Tags: azure, maps, azure-maps

I'm using the Azure Maps web API to show some images on top of a map. I plan to use the [image layer function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/map-add-image-layer#import-a-kml-file-as-ground-overlay) to do it, but I do not want my images to go to Microsoft servers. If I use the image overlay, does it process the images locally on the user's computer or on Microsoft servers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Azure Maps web API (as well as the mobile SDKs) don't send any data you overlay on the map to the cloud (tiles, images, points/lines/polygons...). All rendering is done locally within the client session.

Answer (score 0):

After using the throttle offline simulator in DevTools the image layer still worked, so I'm assuming that means the image is not sent through Microsoft servers.